# React-Router 2.0 Hash History - How to remove query

Tags: react-router

In the module `history`, I could remove the query by:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory';
const history = createBrowserHistory({ queryKey: false });
```

In `react-router 2.0` now that I am getting history from it:

```
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
```

How can I clean up the url and remove the query?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [react-router v2.0.0 Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/latest/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#using-custom-histories):

```
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
// useRouterHistory creates a composable higher-order function
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false })
<Router history={appHistory}/>
```

As you see, `createHashHistory` is imported from `history` package, so you have to install it. Or you can `import { createHashHistory } from 'react-router/node_modules/history'` (as `history` is now a normal dependency of `react-router`)

Answer (score 0):

This works great, thanks.

In case someone is working with browserify (like I am), the code should look like this:

```
var useRouterHistory = require("react-router/lib/useRouterHistory");
var createHashHistory = require("react-router/node_modules/history/lib/createHashHistory");
var appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false });
// finally add it to the router
<Router history={appHistory}>
```